# "Catch" Multiple Buttons with One Method

Tags: java, android, xml, button, android-layout

Forgive me if this has been asked before. I have poured through this site and many others and can't seem to find an answer. I have a working Android app but I'm trying to clean the code up. I have 3 buttons:

```
public Button button1, button2, button3;
```

Then, I have a method that "grabs" the clicks:

```
public void getButtonClick(View view)
{
 switch(view.getId())
 {
  case R.id.button1:
      // Do something button1 related here
  break;

  case R.id.button2:
      // Do something button2 related here
  break;

  case R.id.button3:
      // Do something button3 related here
 }
}
```

What I'd like to know is if there is any way I can have a generic method that will just wait for a button click and grab that variable so that I can avoid the multiple switch-case statements. Something on the line of:

```
public void oneMethodForAll(View view)
{
 clkdBtn = view.getButtonThatWasClicked();
 // Do stuff
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to have the activity implement `View.OnClickListener`:

```
public class FooActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            // Button 1 was clicked
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            // Button 2 was clicked
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That will save you a little bit of typing since you're not creating a bunch of anonymous click handlers, but you will still have to set the `onClickListener` of each button individually.

Comment: This is pretty much what I've been doing except that this example adds the onClickListener() to the equation. I had hoped there was a way to avoid the switch-case statements by sending the android:id of the clicked button to the onClick() method. Doing so would allow a much cleaner, simpler coding of the app. It appears this simply is not allowed however so I'll have to continue the path I was taking. I appreciate all the help from everyone though.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you implement different handlers for different buttons since the action the button will signal is usually different.

You can cast your `View` to a `Button` by using the `View` which is being passed as the sole parameter into your handler.

```
Button clickedButton = (Button)view;
```

If all you care about is the id of the button and your action will be based on that value then create separate handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
clkdBtn = (Button)view;
```

Usually the Button itself isn't used though.  getButtonClick() should *respond* to the button presses with their corresponding action... I'm not sure why you'd need the actual button view itself.

If you want the text that the Button is showing, you could use:

```
String text = ((Button)view).getText();
```

Comment: I'm just needing the ID of the button. If View is incorrect then I will change it. I'm accustomed to PHP actually. This is my first venture into Java.

Comment: the ID of the button is just the view.getId().  If you mean you want to get the variable name of the button (like cancelButton), you can't do that, you'll need to run through the case statements to figure out which one it is.  Either that, or create a custom Button component that has a `getNameOfButton()` method or something. Alternatively, check my post.

Comment: Nah, it's the actual "android:id" I'm wanting to get.

Comment: view.getId() will give you that value from the onClick() method of the ClickListener of the button.